# how to give over application routing to "angularjs" instead of "asp.net mvc"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing, angular8

I have a `asp.net MVC` project with `angular 8` as frontEnd.
i load `angular` files(main.*.js , polyfills.*.js and runtime.*.js and css files) in index of project and all is OK!.
when i call my site (localhost:1234), `angular` files get the role and management. and for example if i click a link like 'Admin/Pages', `angular` loads proportional component.
the problem starts from here:
if i reload this page(localhost:1234/admin/pages) or call it directly from browser address bar (not from a link in `angular` application), `asp.net mvc` searches for route and cannot find it. because there is no other mvc routing except 'Home/Index' (my only mvc view page). 
how can i explain to `asp.net MVC` router : 'Wait bro! leave it to `angular`! it has the route'
in other words, is there any way to distribute some routes to `mvc` and some routes to `angular`?

Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

RouteConfig.cs file:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

HomeController.cs file:(`mvc controller`)

```
 public class HomeController : BaseMvcController
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

app.module.ts file: (`angular`)

```
@NgModule({
//some codes

imports:[
//some codes
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ProductsComponent },
      { path: 'products/:productId', component: ProductDetailsComponent },
      { path: 'products/cart/myCart', component: CartComponent },
      { path: 'Admin/Pages', component: PageManagementComponent }
    ]),
//some codes
]
//some codes
})
```

Comment: If you're using Angular then why also use MVC as well? You've just got two competing UI frameworks, which sounds like a recipe for confusion and incoherence. If you are going to use Angular to control the front end (within a single physical page, I assume) then it would probably make a lot more sense to use a Web API as the back end, to just return data. Then you don't have two separate systems for creating user interface components

Answer (score 0):

So you do not use asp.net MVC routing at all? Try to define a route matching all urls in mvc to get a default page as response, e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "CatchAll",
  "{*.}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

In your Angular client, you will have to use the router events on reloads. Didn't test it.. just to give you a hint.